# VB.NET equivalent of C# event hook up

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb6, interop

This is regarding interop toolkit so UC inside another UC is a given.

I have a user control that fires up an event on button.

I've added a handler to handle it in container user control

```vb
Dim uc As New LoginUC.Login
AddHandler uc.OkClick, AddressOf InteropUserControl_UserControlOk
```

Now I need to raise this event in the parent user control to send it over to VB6 container form.

```vb
Public Event UserControlOk()
Private Sub InteropUserControl_UserControlOk(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.UserControlOk

    RaiseEvent UserControlOk()
End Sub
```

The problem that i see is that once the button is clicked this event keeps firing off non stop. In c# this would be handled by

```cs
if (this.event != null)
    this.event(sender,e);
```

type of code. Any advice how that can be done is VB.NET?

UPDATE:

```vb
Private Sub XamlForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles MyBase.Load

    ' Create the ElementHost control for hosting the
    ' WPF UserControl.
    Dim host As New ElementHost()
    host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

    ' Create the WPF UserControl.
    Dim uc As New LoginUC.Login
    AddHandler uc.OkClick, AddressOf InteropUserControl_UserControlOk

    ' Assign the WPF UserControl to the ElementHost
    '  control's Child property.
    host.Child = uc

    ' Add the ElementHost control to the form's
    ' collection of child controls.
    Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(host)
End Sub
```

This is the code I use to add UC to vb.net user control.
Why would addhandler fire up multiple times?

Comment: Have you seen the call stack that might tell you why that code is being hit more than once?

Comment: "Non-stop" event firing is not a VB.NET or C# feature.  A standard mistake is executing the AddHandler statement multiple times, that runs the event handler repeatedly.

Comment: This is the code I use to add UC. Where did I go wrong, and why would event handler add fire multiple times. This code i got from code project sample for the interop toolkit tut.

Comment: Remove the "Handles" clause on the InteropUserControl_UserControlOk method. It makes no sense that you are raising the UserControlOk event from the method that is handling the UserControlOk event.

Comment: Thank you Dave, that fixed the issue. It caused the VB6 hosting VB.NET control to crash though. The other part of it, raising it's own event to be captured by VB6 code. Any advice there?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe rising the event re-triggers the UC's event again, somehow. Prevent it by adding using a guard variable

```vb
Dim raisingEvent As Boolean = False

Private Sub InteropUserControl_UserControlOk(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.UserControlOk

    If Not raisingEvent Then
        raisingEvent = True
        RaiseEvent UserControlOk()
        raisingEvent = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually Dave's comment helped me out. That was the answer. To answer my second question I figured it out. I've changed the arguments being send to my VB.NET event "Public Event UserControlOk()
" to only two strings instead of sender, eventargs. It seems that VB6 is hanging up on trying to understand the object I am sending to it.

Comment: Olivier, is this how VB.net understand whether or event event is wired up?

Comment: VB's RaiseEvent takes care of the check for whether the event is wired up or not - you don't have the explicit check that C# uses (and indeed this will fail if you try to include it).

Comment: My code doesn't look if the event is wired up, it prevents a recursive call of the event.